# TypeScript Extract not working as expected in Angular compiler

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use the TypeScript `Extract` utility type as a function parameter in an Angular App.

For simplicity i boiled it down to a minimal working example:

```
private static doSomething(param: Extract<string | undefined, undefined>): void {}

this.doSomething(undefined);
```

As i would have expected, the IDE does not show any compile errors. When starting the Angular App i'm getting a compile error though:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
```

The TypeScript version IntelliJ is using is 4.8.4 which is also the version from the package.json, so i assume angular is using it.
Angular CLI version: 14.2.10, Angular compiler version: 14.2.12

Comment: You mean `Exclude` or `Extract`? The description is a bit out of sync with your snippet.

Comment: @user776686 i meant extract and corrected it above, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`undefined` is a special type, if you do not enable `strictNullChecks` then `string | undefined` is equivalent to `string` (`undefined` is assignable to `string`), so it extracts `never`.

If you think about it, it makes little sense to write such code without `strictNullChecks`, it does not make code any safer.